# Issue with compiling SFML project in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks, sfml

Made a simple sprite based 2d game in c++ using SFML. It compiles and runs just fine on linux but I want to be able to compile it on windows

I've downloaded the (supposed) right version of sfml for code::blocks [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amr4Q.png) from https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/ and configured the GNU GCC compiler search paths accordingly:

[compiler search paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwliC.png)

[linker search paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKD5e.png)

[c++11 standard enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRjF0.png)

After running the code I got 152 "undefined reference to ..." errors

Then after adding the libraries to the linker settings

[linker settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZEnW.png)

I got left with those 12 errors:

||=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===|
C:\sfmltest\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5Music12openFromFileERKSs'| C:\sfmltest\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to` _imp___ZN2sf5Music12openFromFileERKSs'|
C:\sfmltest\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf5Music12openFromFileERKSs'| C:\sfmltest\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to` _imp___ZN2sf5Music12openFromFileERKSs'|
C:\sfmltest\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf4Font12loadFromFileERKSs'| C:\sfmltest\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to` _imp___ZN2sf7Texture12loadFromFileERKSsRKNS_4RectIiEE'|
C:\sfmltest\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf7Texture12loadFromFileERKSsRKNS_4RectIiEE'| C:\sfmltest\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to` _imp___ZN2sf7Texture12loadFromFileERKSsRKNS_4RectIiEE'|
C:\sfmltest\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN2sf7Texture12loadFromFileERKSsRKNS_4RectIiEE'| C:\sfmltest\main.o:main.cpp|| undefined reference to` _imp___ZN2sf7Texture12loadFromFileERKSsRKNS_4RectIiEE'|
C:\sfmltest\main.o:main.cpp|| more undefined references to `_imp___ZN2sf7Texture12loadFromFileERKSsRKNS_4RectIiEE' follow|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 12 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|

**what am I missing?**

Comment: Usually libraries with d in their name are Debug libraries, those without it are Release. Linking against them all is very weird. Try link only d-libraries or only no-d-libraries. You can define different sets for Debug && Release.  I wonder if it can help.

Comment: Adding `lsfml-system` `lsfml-window` `lsfml-graphics` to Link libraries under Build Options (for Code::Blocks v20.03) should be sufficient, can you try and put these to your linker settings? (if you are using network and audio just add them too by replacing the suffixes)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define `SFML_STATIC` which is why the linker is looking for `_imp___` (i.e. import) symbols.

Also your listed libraries is wrong. You should only list one set of libraries.
For example Static and Debug = `sfml-*-s-d`
Or Static and Release = `sfml-*-s`

And when you're statically linking, you also need to link SFML's dependencies.

If you follow the [official tutorial](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/start-cb.php) on how to setup SFML with Code::Blocks step by step and don't just looking at the images, things should work just fine.